# IOS mobile access to Google IOT Core REST API authentication authorization scope problem

Tags: ios, json, iphone, iot

一：I would like to ask some questions about our IOS mobile access to Google IOT Core permission scope authentication. We are planning to use API services from Google IOT Core to access device-specific data;

But we encountered the problem of OAuth authentication, requesting the scope of Google API, it may take up to several weeks, I wonder if this is the case?

[OAuth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cFge.jpg)

My application will use the following request scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudiot, https://www.googleapis.com/ auth / cloud-platform I want to be able to view and manage and manage and Create a registered device.

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub Want to use this API to publish subscriptions / topics on your phone, receive device data, and assume: temperature, humidity, alarm values, etc. Mobile terminals can access IoT data through HTTPS (https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/v1/{name=projects/*/locations/*/registries/*}) nodes.

二：Use Google Cloud Functions to connect to the cloud platform to get device data from IOS；

Google Cloud and the device have been successfully bound and deployed through the console, but it is impossible to understand how to write the Google core API from the cloud function so that the device connects to the cloud, IAM grants permissions, or the private key to access the Google API (Purpose: IOS mobile phone calls Google API through cloud functions, implements JSON interface, and gets device data for IOS) Thank you in advance, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My article might be helpful for your problem if you're still having this issue, It shows how to connect to IoT Core using CocoaMQTT and SwiftJWT, you can do something similar but instead of connecting to the specific device you could register the device with a given ES256 public key.

[Controlling you phone from the cloud](https://medium.com/swlh/controlling-your-phone-from-the-cloud-f075b75858c9)